# Spinner dependent problem when going to a textview

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm using a code with a dependent spinner, but I have the following problem:

the spinner loads from a JSON file correctly, but when I try to pass the result of the first spinner to a textview, it does not show me the text of the spinner but this:

I attach image

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUh9N.png)[image]

I use this code for pass a Textview

```
ed_acu.setText(jornadaSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

But i get this error in my Textview "ed_acu", y not the text.

```
com.elgeos.tracker.spinnerCOL.State@a8f178
```

State java

```
public class State {
    private String stateName;
    private List<String> cities;


    public State(String stateName, List<String> cities) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public List<String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

}
```

StateAdapter java

```
public class StateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State> {
    private List<State> stateList = new ArrayList<>();

    public StateAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int spinnerText, @NonNull List<State> stateList) {
        super(context, resource, spinnerText, stateList);
        this.stateList = stateList;
    }

    @Override
    public State getItem(int position) {
        return stateList.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position);

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the state object by calling getItem and
     * Sets the state name to the drop-down TextView.
     *
     * @param position the position of the item selected
     * @return returns the updated View
     */
    private View initView(int position) {
        State state = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jornada_list, null);
        TextView textView =  v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);
        textView.setText(state.getStateName() );
        return v;

    }
}
```

My MainActivity code

```
private void loadStateCityDetails() {
        final List<State> statesList = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonArrayRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, cities_url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray responseArray) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            //Parse the JSON response array by iterating over it
                            for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject response = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String state = response.getString(KEY_STATE);
                                JSONArray cities = response.getJSONArray(KEY_CITIES);
                                List<String> citiesList = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < cities.length(); j++) {
                                    citiesList.add(cities.getString(j));
                                }
                                statesList.add(new State(state, citiesList));
                                states.add(state);

                            }
                            final StateAdapter stateAdapter = new StateAdapter(activity_make_user.this,
                                    R.layout.jornada_list, R.id.spinnerText, statesList);
                            jornadaSpinner.setAdapter(stateAdapter);

                            jornadaSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                    //Populate City list to the second spinner when
                                    // a state is chosen from the first spinner
                                    State cityDetails = stateAdapter.getItem(position);
                                    List<String> cityList = cityDetails.getCities();
                                    ArrayAdapter citiesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity_make_user.this,
                                            R.layout.colegio_list, R.id.citySpinnerText, cityList);
                                    colegioSpinner.setAdapter(citiesAdapter);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                                }
                            });

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                        //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);

    }
```

Comment: where are you setting ed_acu.setText(jornadaSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()); on your Main Activity ? I can not find this line to your Main Activity

Comment: please also add the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override the toString() function in Your StateModel. What you are seeing is the default toString() value.

```
public class State {
    private String stateName;
    private List<String> cities;


    public State(String stateName, List<String> cities) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public List<String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    @Override
    String toString(){
     return stateName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in `StateAdapter`, you are setting the spinner to display `state.getStateName()`. What you are seeing in the other TextView is not an error, but the default `toString()` for your `State` object that you are directly passing to `setText()`. Use `jornadaSpinner.getSelectedItem().getStateName()` instead, and you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

jornadaSpinner.getSelectedItem() returns State object and You need to get state name from that object. So, kindly do the following thing

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(jornadaSpinner.getSelectedItem().getState()))
    ed_acu.setText(jornadaSpinner.getSelectedItem().getState());
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.